# Content behind slide menu(android)

Tags: java, android, menu, slide

I am using the sliding menu library. I don't know how create this effect.

**Example**: If I open the swipe menu, content is pushed to the right.

[image: opening menu with push to right]

**This is what I want to do:** Content stays in place when I open the slide menu.

[image: left right slide menu]

**My Code:**

```
menu = new SlidingMenu(this);
        menu.setMode(SlidingMenu.LEFT_RIGHT);
        menu.setTouchModeAbove(SlidingMenu.TOUCHMODE_FULLSCREEN);

        menu.setShadowWidth(15);
        menu.setFadeDegree(1.0f);

        menu.setShadowWidthRes(R.dimen.shadow_width);
        menu.setShadowDrawable(R.drawable.shadow);

        menu.setSecondaryShadowDrawable(R.drawable.shadow_right);
        menu.attachToActivity(this, SlidingMenu.SLIDING_WINDOW);
        menu.setBehindWidth(400);

        menu.setMenu(R.layout.p_slidemenu_left);
        menu.setSecondaryMenu(R.layout.p_slidingmenu_right);
```

Comment: check SlidingMenu library sample you got whatever you want,

Comment: as far as I know, and if I understood you correctly, it can't be achieved with that library. It can be done with standard NavigationDrawer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be accomplished very easily through the standard Navigation Drawer by using the DrawerLayout in the Support Library.

For more information on how to get started, refer to: https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html